# spark-sql stuck at BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 when calculating sql statement

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Output as this and stuck at last line:

```
17/09/07 06:01:35 INFO ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 10.0.0.193/10.0.0.193:2181, initiating session  
17/09/07 06:01:35 INFO ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server 10.0.0.193/10.0.0.193:2181, sessionid = 0x15e4bc9518103cc, negotiated timeout = 40000  
17/09/07 06:01:35 INFO RegionSizeCalculator: **Calculating region sizes for table "event_data".**  
17/09/07 06:01:35 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: processCmd at CliDriver.java:376  
17/09/07 06:01:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (processCmd at CliDriver.java:376) with 1 output partitions  
17/09/07 06:01:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (processCmd at CliDriver.java:376)  
17/09/07 06:01:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()  
17/09/07 06:01:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()  
17/09/07 06:01:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[4] at processCmd at CliDriver.java:376), which has no missing parents  
17/09/07 06:01:36 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 16.6 KB, free 414.1 MB)  
17/09/07 06:01:36 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 8.8 KB, free 414.1 MB)  
17/09/07 06:01:36 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 10.0.0.199:43329 (size: 8.8 KB, free: 414.4 MB)  
17/09/07 06:01:36 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1007  
17/09/07 06:01:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[4] at processCmd at CliDriver.java:376) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))  
17/09/07 06:01:36 INFO YarnScheduler: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks  
17/09/07 06:01:37 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Requesting 1 new executor because tasks are backlogged (new desired total will be 1)  
17/09/07 06:01:42 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (10.0.0.248:55616) with ID 1  
17/09/07 06:01:42 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: New executor 1 has registered (new total is 1)  
17/09/07 06:01:42 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, ip-10-0-0-248.cn-north-1.compute.internal, executor 1, partition 0, RACK_LOCAL, 5053 bytes)  
17/09/07 06:01:42 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager ip-10-0-0-248.cn-north-1.compute.internal:34192 with 2.8 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, ip-10-0-0-248.cn-north-1.compute.internal, 34192, None)  
17/09/07 06:01:42 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on ip-10-0-0-248.cn-north-1.compute.internal:34192 (size: 8.8 KB, free: 2.8 GB)  
17/09/07 06:01:42 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on ip-10-0-0-248.cn-north-1.compute.internal:34192 (size: 28.8 KB, free: 2.8 GB)
```

Spark SQL connect to hive and the table which name is `event_data` and it is a external table stored in hbase.
Besides, It will be success if I manipulate a hive table (NOT from hbase), such as, `select count(*) from mytest01`.

Sometimes is will stuck at `BlockManagerInfo: Removed`:

```
17/09/07 06:31:18 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 1  
17/09/07 06:31:18 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on 10.0.0.199:43329 in memory (size: 28.8 KB, free: 414.4 MB)  
17/09/07 06:31:18 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on ip-10-0-0-248.cn-north-1.compute.internal:34192 in memory (size: 28.8 KB, free: 2.8 GB)
```

How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Do you find a solution? i met the same problem now

Comment: @LeylaLee, I'm not clearly remember the problem here. I headache last year about spark is I'm use AWS Spark to submit jobs in command line. If you also do this, I recommend you can try migrate to other spark lib, such as Apache Spark.

Comment: I actually i am using Apache Spark ;0

Comment: Do you remember now? I would really like to know what you had to change to to allow the blockmanager to add further broadcasts

Comment: I am having the same issue does anyone know how to solve this.

Comment: same issue too.

Answer (score 0):

When you do spark submit use the flags:

```
--driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 6g
```

Paste this right after "spark-submit"